# I am trying to utilize griddb for my big data project, but installation is stuck at a step. How to proceed?

Tags: installation, griddb

I am trying to utilize griddb for my big data project, but installation is stuck at a step. How to proceed?

My platform is Azure VM with 1GB RAM and 30GB disk.
OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I am installing as guided here:
https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-apt-get

I expected to drop into the db shell for further operations. But I got a warning and an error.

Notification on apt update:

```
W: Conflicting distribution: https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.3 InRelease (expected griddb/5.3 but got )
```

Error on starting shell:

```
$ sudo su gsadm
<shell>$ gs_sh
/usr/bin/gs_sh: 47: java: not found
```

Comment: Try `java -version` to check what version of java, if any, you have installed

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Java was missing. Perhaps they should list out the system requirements and dependencies on the getting started page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated, you need java installed and it needs to be accessible by the gsadm (griddb) user to drop into the CLI